# Blank Checkout Page after installing extension

Tags: magento2.3, checkout

I Installed a Marketplace extension on magento and it works well.

Except that the checkout page is now blank ( with only the logo ).

I tried debugging but i couldn't resolve it.

The one thing i found ( from template hints ) that the only file that doesn't get called is
`./vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml`
I checked the di.xml from the extension and i didn't see anything being replaced from the plugin in the checkout process.

Can anyone help me in debugging this or know what can be the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check log file in var folder or disable that module so get Idea about or check console.

Comment: Enable developer mode and you should see error.

Comment: I have enabled developer mode(with all errors displayed) but i don't see any error, it's just not calling the onepage file.

Comment: Check console.log in browser may help to reveal what problem! Also you can check file logs in var/log from your project magento folder